# Get output from scans in hbase shell

Tags: hbase

Is there any way I can output the results from a scan in the hbase shell to a file? I'm assuming this is easy but I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I know that this post is quite old but i was searching something about HBase myself and came across with it.

Well i don't know if this is the best way to do it, but you can definitely use the scripting option HBase gives you. Just open a shell (preferably go to the directory bin of HBase) and run

```
echo "scan 'foo'" | ./hbase shell > myText
```

where foo is the name of the table you want to scan. If you then open myText you will see the results in there. Hope i helped!

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that hbase is fairly chatty, so you don't just get the command output, you also get a bunch of hbase conversation.  If you want to get data and parse it, it's pretty icky.

Comment: @KenWilliams Also it is little slow. Is there any way faster way you know. Actually I have to execute a command in loop for 24 times and it is taking a lot of time and I don't want to write a java code to do that.

Comment: @sahu not that I know of - the best option might be to write the results to HDFS first, then export from HDFS to the local filesystem.

Comment: It works! Need to run in directly in shell. Not in HBase shell prompt

Answer (score 10):

Another option using an EOF here doc, potentially more customizable:

```
hbase shell <<EOF >myText
scan 'foo'
EOF
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use here strings too (if your shell supports them):

```
$ hbase shell <<< "scan 'sometable'" > myoutput.txt
```

Above I'm doing this in Bash on a Linux system, for example.

Answer (score 2):

ex : **file.sh** contains 
scan '*tablename*';

Execute bellow command to capture result to log file....

```
hbase shell < file.sh(which contains hbase commands) > output.lo
```