# How to get image (stored in avro format) from hbase and store in local file system

Tags: hbase, avro

I have used flume agent to transfer image(.jpg) to HBase. Now I want to fetch that image and store in the disk(local file system), Is there a utility which can convert an image(stored as Avro) to actual image & store in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest to do it in 2 phases.

1. Use `hbase shell` to `scan` table and extract content to file [Get output from scans in hbase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035475/get-output-from-scans-in-hbase-shell)
2. Use *avrò-tools* to convert avrò file into original file (image?) `java -jar ~/avro-tools-1.7.4.jar fromjson`

Comment: I could import data into a file but im unable to convert file to image using avro-tools available options...

Comment: Available tools:
     compile  .
     concat  
   fragtojson  
     fromjson  
     fromtext  
      getmeta  
    getschema  
          idl  
       induce  reflection.
   jsontofrag  
      recodec  
  rpcprotocol  
   rpcreceive  
      rpcsend  Sends a single RPC message.
       tether  
       tojson  
       totext  
trevni_random  schema.trevni_tojson