# How to dump an HBase table?

Tags: hbase

(being new in HBase)

I've seen if I generate myself a file with the "put" command in each line, I can add each of it on a row in the HBase table using the "shell" command against it:

```
hbase shell newcontent.sc
```

where this file looks like:

```
put 'tablename', 'key1', 'column', 'value2'
...
put 'tablename', 'keyN', 'column', 'valueN'
```

Is there a command provided by HBase to automatically generate a file with this format?
So I can store a table in a mysqldump fashion to use it somewhere else or as a backup

Post Edition: I don't need a tool building csv files or other stuff (I know how to do it). I am looking for the equivalent to mysqldump for HBase (to make it simple and automatic) if it exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i dump hbase table in a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724855/how-can-i-dump-hbase-table-in-a-text-file)